# Mocha ES6 tests supported?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to use [expect](https://github.com/Automattic/expect.js) tests with [mocha](http://mochajs.org/), written in ES6, and am getting `TypeError` even with a simple test case:

```
import expect from "expect"; 

describe('Example', () => {
  it('should just work', (done) => {
    expect(5).to.eql(5);
    done();
  });
});
```

I'm using Babel to convert and run the tests:

`./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel/register example.js`

Which results in:

```
  Example
    1) should just work


  0 passing (76ms)
  1 failing

  1) Example should just work:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'eql' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (example.js:5:17)
```

Is this not supported, or am I missing something critical?

Versions:

- *babel 5.5.6*
- *expect 1.6.0*
- *mocha 2.2.5*

Comment: Note, that in `babel 6.x` you should write `--compilers js:babel-core/register`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a head scratcher at first, but you're using importing the wrong expect!

Change your import to:

```
import expect from "expect.js";
```

And everything works.  [Here](https://github.com/mjackson/expect) is the `expect` module.  The module you're 'expect'ing to use is called `expect.js`

Hope this helps, and sorry for the bad pun :)

Edit:  You'll also have to be sure to `npm install expect.js` as well!

Comment: I can't believe that was it! Thank you! I casually excluded the `.js` from the `import` thinking "oh, I can omit file extensions from imports".

Comment: What's funny is I did exactly the same thing as you when I was trying to reproduce this.