# In a Babel project workflow, does it make more sense to run unit tests firstly and transpile secondly or vice-versa?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

In a workflow (grunt, gulp, npm), would it be better to:

1. Test
2. Transpile to ES5
3. Deliver (bundle, minify, etc)

OR

1. Transpile to ES5
2. Test
3. Deliver (bundle, minify, etc)

1st approach, I would give a pre-processor to my unit test library (as in `./node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers js:babel/register example.js`) and only then I would proceed to transpile. 2nd approach, I would test whatever is the output from the transpilation step.

Are there any caveats with either #1 or #2? Looking forward to understand pros and cons with both approaches.

Comment: How would you go about running your tests on untranspiled ES6? Seems like no matter what you need to be running the code as ES5 when running tests, so I'm not sure what the difference is between your two cases.

Comment: I'm considering testing ES6 using babel as a pre-compiler to Mocha, as in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014826/mocha-es6-tests-supported

Comment: As long as your configuration for mocha's compiler is the same, it seems like your question is kind of moot, since both run the tests against ES5. It's entirely your preference how you want to do it.

Comment: You are correct, let me rephrase the question. I actually wanted to know what makes more sense from the point of building the workflow: 1st testing, then transpiling, or vice-versa?

Comment: I have just rephrased the question and title. Would you kindly read it again and tell me what you think? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me it seems to make sense that you would run tests on the code that is going to be shipped to your clients.

By that logic, you should be running tests against the transpiled code.

But there are two trains of thought here:

1. we didn't write babel and we shouldn't be testing its effect
2. it doesn't matter that we didn't write babel, we should test if our post-transpile code works no matter what

For certain dependencies, I subscribe to #1, but for build tools such as babel, I tend to subscribe to #2

Babel is great, but it's not perfect. It can make mistakes too, and I think it's better to be defensive and catch that in your builds/tests if possible.

For other things like including a lib in your code, I am more likely to trust in the test suite provided. For example, if I were to write a React app, I wouldn't bother writing test for React-specific functionalities.

Comment: Gotcha. You got exactly the bouncing of ideas I was looking for. Thanks. For now I will go with #1 keeping in mind that it would not hurt to do #2 for new/unstable ES6 features that I might be using down the road.